# How do i solve typescript error No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings, angular-services

I wrote a typescript function for a service to return an observable in angular and I encountered the error  Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'.

How do I solve it. Below is the link to my code.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IProperty } from '../property/IProperty.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HousingService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //method for getting all the realEstate properties
  getAllProperties(): Observable<IProperty[]> {
    return this.http.get('../../data/properties.json').pipe(
      map(data => {
        const propertiesArray: Array<IProperty> = [];
        for (const id in data) {
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            propertiesArray.push(data[id]);
          }
        }
        return propertiesArray;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe instead of using keys you could use values directly? `const propertiesArray = Object.values(data);`

Answer (score 0):

`http.get` is generic and lets you pass in the expected type of data, so you could use `{ [key: string]: string }` as the type:

```
return this.http.get<{ [key: string]: string }>('../../data/properties.json').pipe(
```

Comment: I tried doing that but i'm getting a new error : Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IProperty'. Could you help me rewrite the function if possible. IProperty is my interface in this case.